# Using background Worker to insert Text file into a listBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

When I add this line of code inside loop

```
myCollection.Add(new FetchData(line));
```

it throws

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread

I have also tried using this, but didn't work:

```
mqttUpload.ItemsSource = MyList;
```

The Progress Bar updates and I am also able to print lines, the only problem is that I cannot add the data to the ListBox.

This is how  my data looks like inside the txt file, this file contains 3500 lines.
[image]

Here is what i have tried.

```
public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
{

    public static List<string> Mylist = new List<string>();
    ObservableCollection<FetchData> myCollection = new  ObservableCollection<FetchData>();

    public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mqttUpload.ItemsSource = myCollection;

        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged +=backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += jobfinish;

    }

    public static UserControl2 uploadData;

    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
    public static string FilePath = "";

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var files = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            var line = files[i];
            Mylist.Add(line);
            int percentage = (int)((i / (double)files.Length) * 100.0);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage);
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }

    public void jobfinish(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(  "finish");

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)// progress change
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

Fetch class

```
public class FetchData
{
    public string fetchData { get; set; }

    public FetchData(string fetchData)
    {
        this.fetchData = fetchData;
    }
}
```

Here is XAML code

```
<ListBox Margin="10,64,0,-434" Grid.Column="2" Name="mqttUpload" 
         Padding="20,0,0,0" Background="#18191A"  Foreground="#F5980C" Grid.Row="2" />
```

My goal is to read data line by line while showing progress bar and finally show data inside the ListBox.

This is how data suppose to be shown in the Listbox. in this image i am reading data from database. i want to achieve same but reading from txt file.
[image]

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Your real issue is that 99.9% of the actual CPU work that needs to be done, *must* happen on the UI thread: that is rendering all the controls that display the lines in your list view. You can’t really display a progress bar for UI rendering work. You best bet is virtualization. You should simply avoid doing all the unnecessary rendering and then there’s no need for a progress bar because your UI loads instantly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most important rule: you can only touch the GUI from the GUI (main) thread.

Your `Mylist.Add(line);` is breaking that rule.

As an alternative you can use the Progress event:

```
  backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage, line);
```

and then

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)// progress change
{
   progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
   string line = (string) e.State;
   Mylist.Add(line);  // ok, this runs on the main thread
}
```

Comment: well i was able to get data  into MyList before also, the only problem is that I cannot add the data to the ListBox. i believe this will be done by using  ObservableCollection  i replaced Mylist.Add(line);  to myCollection.Add(new FetchData(line));  using your code  my gui freezes. didn't worked also.

Comment: That `FetchData` can not possibly change anything. My code should not freeze, there must be something else you did not post.

Comment: But the best thing here is to avoid this: no user can or wants to read 3500 lines. Your GUI is not your Data Layer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wait until jobFinished?

You can send data via the ReportsProgress.

[BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress Method (Int32, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Update the UI a line a time is a lot of overhead.  I would use async file IO and read the first 100 lines then read the whole file.

Comment: i don't mind waiting until job finish, but at last it should show data into my ListBox in gui.

Comment: Then do it in jobFinished.